# Distinct Sums from a list of positive integers

Tags: python, math, sum, combinations

This question troubles me for couple days already.

The question is "given a list of coins e.g. [10, 50, 100] and a list of quantity of coins e.g. [1, 2, 1], return the number of distinct sums of coins"

example:

`coins = [10, 50, 100]`

`quantity = [1, 2, 1]`

The function should return **9**

`[10], [50], [100], [10, 50], [10, 100], [50, 100], [10, 50, 100], [50, 50, 100], [1, 50, 50, 100]`

My approach:

a) find out all distinct sums from the **coins, list of coins** and save those sums into a set
b) go through **quantity**, add each coin which has more than one to the existing distinct sums in the set

This approach works but performance is really bad. For example, if `coins=[1, 2]` and `quantity=[10000, 1]`, it will take too long to process.

Please throw me some better ideas how to approach this question. Thanks

My code:

```
def possibleSums(coins, quantity):
    if len(coins) != len(quantity):
        return -1
    sums = set(coins[:])
    coins_len = len(coins)
    for len_ in range(1, coins_len):
        for s_idx in range(coins_len):
            if s_idx + len_ <= coins_len:
                tmp = sum(coins[s_idx:s_idx+len_])
                for i in coins[s_idx+len_:]:
                    sums.add(tmp+i)
    idx = 0
    while idx < coins_len:
        if quantity[idx] > 1:
            for _ in range(quantity[idx] - 1):
                tmp = set()
                for element in sums:
                    if element + coins[idx] not in sums:
                        tmp.add(element+coins[idx])
                sums |= tmp
        idx += 1
    # END WHILE
    return len(sums)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete search algorithm for combinations of coins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642133/complete-search-algorithm-for-combinations-of-coins)

Comment: @nj2237 Thanks.

Comment: Also solution with sets:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783747/number-of-distinct-sums-from-non-empty-groupings-of-possibly-very-large-lists/48785897#48785897  (I expect that solution with list/array should be faster but gets more memory for sparse result)